# Multiple grids in Panel

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have MainTable and SecondTable what I want to do:
[image: Example]

MainTable and SecondTable are mostly same (example):

```
    {{1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 0}}
```

All this is in function:

```
    function[] := Module[{}, Panel[Manipulate[
```

All is working smoothly but I can't get those grids to their position. It's always print only one. I was searching and spent many hours without any result. I appreciates any help.

**Example:**

```
function[] := Module[{}, Panel[Manipulate[
MainTable = {{x, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 0}};
SecondTable = {{y, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 5}, {5, 5, 5}};
Grid[{MainTable, SecondTable}, Frame -> All],
{{x, 1, "Input 1"}, ControlType -> InputField}, 
{{y, 1, "Input 2"}, ControlType -> InputField}],
FrameMargins -> Automatic]]
```

Comment: Post a minimal *working* example of code that has the issue.  That can be looked at and suggestions made to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
   function[] := 
   Module[{}, 
   Panel[Manipulate[
   MainTable = {{x, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 0}};
   SecondTable = {{y, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 5}, {5, 5, 5}};
   Grid[{{Grid[MainTable, Frame -> All]}, {Grid[SecondTable, Frame -> All]}}], 
   {{x, 1, "Input 1"}, ControlType -> InputField}, 
   {{y, 1, "Input 2"}, ControlType -> InputField}, Alignment -> Center]]]
```